# Adding rdf:type to a blank node in Ontorefine

Tags: graphdb, blank-nodes, ontorefine

I'm using Ontorefine within GraphDB to create RDF triples from a csv source. It seems impossible to add a rdf:type when the subject is a blank node.

When you hit the arrow in the bottom right corner of an object that is a blank node, you can type a owl:Restiction (or rdf:type owl:Restriction for that matter), but after applying, it disappears.

Even if you manually add the statement (in the JSON source) that this blank node has rdf:type owl:Restriction as property en object, it still does not create the actual triple. See picture below. The configuration is there, but the example states: empty empty. And indeed, no triple is created.

[image]

Is this in someway a feature of Ontotext, or is this a bug? In several occasions this is needed, for instance in creating a restriction in OWL.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug! We're going through stackoverflow and adding to the OR product backlog. Our reference: https://ontotext.atlassian.net/browse/OR-375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was addressed in the newer versions of the tool.

Currently the latest [Ontotext Refine](https://www.ontotext.com/products/ontotext-refine) version is `1.2`, where the issue is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is still present in the tool but it seems to be a purely a bug in the mapping UI . If you produce a mapping without the `rdf:type` and generate a SPAQRL query from that mapping, you can just add the `rdf:type` in the `construct`/`insert` part of the mapping query and use it to produce RDF or insert it GraphDB.